# How to store ajax result in php variable?

Tags: php, ajax

```
<?php $shoppingcart = $jcart->display_cart(); ?>

<?php echo $shoppingcart; ?>
```

How can i store the ajax result(HTML code) in the php variable so i can save the HTML code in databases and display the result again?

Please Help. thank you

Comment: What do you mean by 'ajax result'? To display the result multiple times you have to use a foreach or for loop.

Comment: Your approach seems completely wrong. You get data from PhP and then display data in HTML. I'd suggest reading about server-side/client-side stuff & MVC

Comment: I think your question would be, how to cache html, using PHP, right?

Answer (score 0):

The ajax data comes often through GET or POST. PHP stores those on global `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables, respectively.

For instace, when accessing an URL like 'http://localhost:8080/?key1=value1&key2=value2', PHP will fill the $_GET reserved variable with the following array:

`[ 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2' ].`

Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php and http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php for more information about those reseved variables.

Comment: thank for the reply. I know it will store in php value but I try to store the html code in databases so i can display the table again. save some work. lol.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a sessions and cookies to store the results. You can archive this by using javascript or a jquery plugin jquery cookie https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie